# Force iframe to have an ID

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have some content on my site that can be embeded by other domains. What happens is that my iframes need to have an ID to run some javascript.

This is the iframe code I provide to my users:

```
<iframe src="http://www.example.com/embed/2854" id="zframe" width="100%" height="460" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

When the users remove the frame ID, my javascript stops working.

Is there a way wo force the iframe to have an ID via javascript?

Bellow is my implementation to try forcing the ID usage on my iframe when users remove the ID from the iframe code I provide:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
document.getElementByTagName('iframe')[0].setAttribute("id", "zframe"); 
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If the user wants to change something in their browser, you can't (and shouldn't be able to) stop them. Is there another issue that is causing users to want to removed your `id`? (Also, would it help to select the iframe by something other than its id, like a class or attribute?)

Comment: You can't. You can do anything on your side (eg: backend) but not on the client-side.

Comment: I don't see how your JS can stop working if it is running in the page inside the frame. If you were giving them HTML that included an `<iframe>` **and** a `<script>` element then I could see that causing problems (and those are potentially solvable problems).

Comment: @Quentin My javascript only works `onClick` in iframe ID. If my users remove the ID, the javascript has no reference to work

Comment: @bpy — That doesn't really have anything to do with my comment.